# Memory DB in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, multi-tenant

These days I'm working with hibernate, I have used "hsqldb" as memory db with JPA,In our application we use "multi tenancy",so we are using hibernate. can i use memory base db with multi tenancy in hibernate?

```
@Autowired
protected TenantBasedSessionFactory tenantBasedSessionFactory;

Session session = tenantBasedSessionFactory.getTenantBasedSession("1")
```

Can I use this way to use memory db with hibernate ?

Thank you,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at H2 instead of HSQLDB (but that is personal opinion).  There is nothing different really about using an in-memory versus persistent database with Hibernate (with or without multi-tenancy).

Comment: Thank you Steve,I'll try with that, Is there any advantage over the HsqlDB ?